# WSUS Server shows - Not Yet Reported

Tags: wsus, windows-update

Server OS - Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Client OS - Windows 7

WSUS Server Version - 3.2.7600.226

Around 4 days has been passed, still Windows Client is showing Last Status Report as 'Not Yet Reported'

I have run the wuauclt /detectnow command from 2nd day onward, still it shows the Last Status Report as 'Not Yet Reported'

Please see the print-screen for more Detail. and let me know Why? it is showing Report as 'Not Yet Reported' and what should i do, to resolve the issue.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This can be due to a version mismatch between the Windows update agent and the WSUS server. WSUS needs to be at version 3.2.7600.251 or later in order to properly communicate with clients at version 7.6.7600.256 or later.

To Check WSUS Server Version, Go to --> Start --> Administrative Tools --> Windows Server Update Service-->  Click on Help Menu --> About Update Services

To Check WSUS Client Version --> On Windows Client --> Go to C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log --> Search Client Version for eg:- Client version: Core: 7.6.7600.256